# Increase and Decrease font size using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I Have News Website. I Want Put Button for User Increase  and Decrease Page Font Size I Set Default text Size in Css Like This

```
 <style>
        * {
            font-size: 12px ;
        }
    </style>
```

and HTML code

```
 <div>
    <p class="myp">The following script can be used to allow visitors to increase or decrease the size of text on your page. This can be useful for visitors who have trouble reading smaller text and allows them to increase it to something they can view more easily.</p>

    </div>
        <a href="#" class="increaseFont">increaseFont</a>
        <a href="#" class="decreaseFont">decreaseFont</a>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // Reset Font Size

                var originalFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');

                $(".resetFont").click(function () {
                    $('html').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
                });
                // Increase Font Size
                $(".increaseFont").click(function () {
                    var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');

                    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
                    $('html').css('font-size', 0);
                    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum * 1.2;
                    $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
                    return false;
                });
                // Decrease Font Size
                $(".decreaseFont").click(function () {
                    var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
                    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
                    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum * 0.8;
                    $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
```

but Not Work. But When Remove Css Code Text Work Fine. Please help me. Thanks All.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your styling says to target `*` (everything) but in the javascript code you're only targeting the html element.

Change your CSS to target the html element.

```
    html
    {
        font-size: 12px ;
    }
```

As a side note, your current code will be pretty hard to maintain when you need to change multiple elements. See if something like this will work better.

Note that resetting the font is still only done for single elements. Ideally you could refactor the code to take in an array of objects for multiple elements

```
var changeFontSize = function (increaseFont) {
    var fontTargets = new Array('html', 'p');

    fontTargets.forEach(function (element) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var newFontSize;
        var currentFontSize = $element.css('font-size');
        var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);

        if (increaseFont) {
            $element.css('font-size', 0);
            newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum * 1.2;
        } else {
            newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum * 0.8;
        }

        $element.css('font-size', newFontSize);
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Reset Font Size
    var originalFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');

    $(".resetFont").click(function () {
        $('html').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
    });
    // Increase Font Size
    $(".increaseFont").on('click', function () {
        changeFontSize(true);
    });
    // Decrease Font Size
    $(".decreaseFont").on('click', function () {
        changeFontSize(false);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/My2xt/1/